# Can't make C++ program use high enough precision

Tags: c++, c++11, precision

```
...
cout << setprecision(100) << pow((3+sqrt(5.0)),28) << endl;
...
```

outputs

```
135565048129406451712
```

which isn't precise enough but.

```
$ bc <<< "scale = 100; (3+sqrt(5.0))^28"
```

outputs

```
135565048129406369791.9994684648068789538123313610677119237534230237579838585720347675878761558402979025019238688523799354
```

which is what I want.  I'm setting the `cout` precision so it must be the `sqrt`, `pow` or `+` are losing the precision?

Comment: `bc` has infinite precision, a `double` in C++ does not.

Comment: You need to use a fixed decimal precision number being able to represent this at all. `double` doesn't support this.

Comment: Standard doubles usually have only 64 bits of precision, which is far less than 100 significant digits. You'll need to use an arbitrary precision math library if you want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting precision on `cout` doesn't have any effect on how the underlying computation is done in C++. `float`s typically have about 8 digits of precision, `doubles` about 16; your C++ output has only the first 15 digits matching the bc output.

If you want more precision then you'll have to use another method, such as an arbitrary precision numerical library. That's how the `bc` program implements arbitrary precision math.

For example, using:

https://gmplib.org

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  mpf_set_default_prec(402);

  mpf_class a = 3_mpf + sqrt(5_mpf);
  mpf_class output;
  mpf_pow_ui(output.get_mpf_t(), a.get_mpf_t(), 28);

  std::cout << std::setprecision(121);
  std::cout << output << '\n';
}
```

This prints:

> 135565048129406369791.9994684648068789538123313610677119237534230237579838585720347675878761558402979528909982661363879709

Interestingly this is different from the output of `bc <<< "scale = 100; (3+sqrt(5.0))^28"`, but if you set the scale higher for bc you'll see that gmp's output is correct.

It looks like bc is willing to print out however many digits it has even if the operands to expressions that produced those digits didn't have enough precision to get them right. In contrast GMP appears to set the precision for results based on what's accurate given the precision of the inputs.

Comment: Correct, except for the false assertion that an object of any given floating-point type has some predetermined precision according to the abstraction that is C++.